HELP：how to fix my Ubuntu22.04system
My operating system is Ubuntu 22.04. I previously downloaded some offline installation packages for offline installation of cifs-utils:
cifs-utils_2%3a6.14-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb
libcap-ng0_0.7.9-2.2build3_amd64.deb
libkeyutils1_1.6.1-2ubuntu3_amd64.deb
libkrb5-3_1.19.2-2ubuntu0.3_amd64.deb
libpam0g_1.4.0-11ubuntu2.4_amd64.deb
libtalloc2_2.3.3-2build1_amd64.deb
libwbclient0_2%3a4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu1.5_amd64.deb
python3_3.10.6-1~22.04_amd64.deb

After the execution was completed, the installation was not successful. It prompted that cifs-utils was installed but not configured. After connecting to the Internet, I started to get errors when using apt install cifs-utils. The error message is as follows:
$ sudo apt install cifs-utils
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading status information... Done
cifs-utils is already at the latest version (2:6.14-1ubuntu0.1).
You may need to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct the problems.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  libgssapi-krb5-2: Depends: libkrb5-3 (= 1.19.2-2) but 1.19.2-2ubuntu0.3 is to be installed
  libkrb5-3: Depends: libkrb5support0 (= 1.19.2-2ubuntu0.3) but 1.19.2-2 is to be installed
    Breaks: libkrb5-3:i386 (!= 1.19.2-2ubuntu0.3) but 1.19.2-2 is to be installed
  libkrb5-3:i386: Breaks: libkrb5-3 (!= 1.19.2-2ubuntu0.3) but 1.19.2-2 is to be installed
  libsmbclient: Depends: libwbclient0 (= 2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.2) but 2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu1.5 is to be installed
  samba-libs: Depends: libwbclient0 (= 2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.2) but 2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu1.5 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

I tried methods like apt --fix-broken install, but they didn't work. Now I get errors when installing other packages as well. For example, when I try to install aptitude, I get the same error.
I need help: How can I fix this? The system is very important, and I don't dare to delete packages easily. I need to restore the installation of cifs or nfs-common to mount NFS storage.
Thank you very much!

GPT suggests using sudo dpkg --purge <package_name> to purge the conflicting packages and reinstall them, including the ones listed previously. However, you are concerned that purging these packages might crash your system and are hesitant to use the command.

After a mess like this a fresh install will be the quickest and cleanest fix. Do not  download for off line install next time. There is no reason you can not install the packages right from the sources.

The title should briefly describe the problem instead of asking for help. EVERY question here seeks help.

cifs-utils is in the repository so no need to use manual install. Probably best to purge the current install and get it from package manager which will sort out any dependencies. If that fails then you have a deeper problem with the OS.
